# dynatree show grandchildren at different <div> location

Tags: dynatree

I have the dynatree working fine. However I need something like this:

When click on "**Sub-item 2.1.1"**, the children (*sub-item 2.1.1.1 & 2.1.2.2*) will show at right hand panel (in another div element)

I don't want them to be appear as children for "Sub-item 2.1.1" in tree.

How can I achieve this?